# Bottom navigation prevents last item of recyclerView

Tags: android, android-viewpager, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, bottomnavigationview

I am designing an application. Main activity contains tabLayout. Each tab has RecyclerView. However I can't see last item of the RecyclerView. I think bottomNavigation prevents. How can I change last position of viewPager? What should I do? You can see my main activity layout code below.
My app image is: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2WRX.png)

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_mail_white_24dp"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:onClick="openChat"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvProfile"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_person_white_24dp"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:onClick="openProfile"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Where2Stay"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
           android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/viewpager"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation">

    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
        app:backgroundTint="#ff0000"
        android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"

        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Try to add bottom margin into view pager with your BottomNavigationView height

Comment: Or hide the bottom navigation when user scrolls through your app

Comment: it causes the navBar to move @Skullper

Comment: I can't hide. It must be on screen @NovoLucas

Comment: @SergeantAvan try to add top anchor to bottom view into view pager

Comment: exist bottomNav's anchor is look like
`app:layout_anchor="@+id/viewpager"
 app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center`
@Skullper

Comment: @SergeantAvan yes, but your view pager's height is match_parent

Comment: i changed viewpager's height to 464 dp, then when I swipe, bottom nav following up :D @Skullper

Comment: @SergeantAvan fixed height is bad. Because it will different on smartphones